# Using customview from library in project

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have `CustomLayout` class declared in a library customAndroidLibrary. This `CustomLayout` extends `ViewGroup`. Now I  want to use this CustomLayout in my `layout.xml` which is in my project. I have included this library in my project.

CustomLayout class

```
package com.android.custom;
public class CustomLayout extends ViewGroup {
    .....
}
```

layout.xml

```
<com.android.custom.CustomLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/animation_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</com.android.custom.CustomLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.android.ui;    
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    }
}
```

But it is throwing `ClassNotFoundException`.
Even it is not detecting my `Activity` also if I am using the custom view in `layout.xml`
If I am using simple `TextView` in `layout.xml`. Then it is not giving any error.

Comment: Just to verify, have you added your library to class path of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it on my own.

```
<com.android.custom.CustomLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    class="com.android.custom.CustomLayout"
    android:id="@+id/animation_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</com.android.custom.CustomLayout>
```